# erro ao enviar email no php utilzando o phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Segue meu código php e html

```
<?php


require("PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){


$enviaFormularioParaNome = 'Lucas';
$enviaFormularioParaEmail = 'email@email.com';

$caixaPostalServidorNome = 'user';
$caixaPostalServidorEmail = 'email@email.com';
$caixaPostalServidorSenha = 'senha';


$remetenteNome  = $_POST['nome'];
$remetenteEmail = $_POST['email'];
$assunto  = $_POST['tipoQuarto'];
$mensagem = $_POST['telefone'];
$entrada = $_POST['data1'];
$saida = $_POST['data2'];

$mensagemConcatenada = 'Solicitação de Reserva'.'<br/>'; 
$mensagemConcatenada .= '-------------------------------<br/><br/>'; 
$mensagemConcatenada .= 'Nome: '.$remetenteNome.'<br/>'; 
$mensagemConcatenada .= 'E-mail: '.$remetenteEmail.'<br/>'; 
$mensagemConcatenada .= 'Quarto: '.$assunto.'<br/>';
$mensagemConcatenada .= 'Entrada: '.$entrada.'<br/>';
$mensagemConcatenada .= 'Saída: '.$saida.'<br/>';
$mensagemConcatenada .= '<br/>'; 
$mensagemConcatenada .= 'Telefone: "'.$mensagem.'"<br/>';




require_once('PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth  = true;
$mail->Charset   = 'utf8_decode()';
$mail->Host  = 'smtp.'.substr(strstr($caixaPostalServidorEmail, '@'), 1);
$mail->Port  = '587';
$mail->Username  = $caixaPostalServidorEmail;
$mail->Password  = $caixaPostalServidorSenha;
$mail->From  = $caixaPostalServidorEmail;
$mail->FromName  = utf8_decode($caixaPostalServidorNome);
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Subject  = utf8_decode($assunto);
$mail->Body  = utf8_decode($mensagemConcatenada);


$mail->AddAddress($enviaFormularioParaEmail,utf8_decode($enviaFormularioParaNome));

if(!$mail->Send()){
$mensagemRetorno = 'Erro ao enviar formulário: '. print($mail->ErrorInfo);
}else{
$mensagemRetorno = 'Formulário enviado com sucesso!';
} 


}?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 tm-contact-form-input col-lg-offset-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select name="tipoQuarto" id="finputtipo" class="form-control">
                            <option value="Quarto Individual">Quarto Individual</option>
                            <option value="Quarto Duplo">Quarto Duplo</option>
                            <option value="Quarto Triplo">Quarto Triplo</option>
                            <option value="Apartamento Individual">Apartamento Individual</option>
                            <option value="Apartamento Duplo">Apartamento Duplo</option>
                            <option value="Apartamento Triplo">Apartamento Triplo</option>
                            <option value="Apartamento individual com Ar">Apartamento individual com Ar</option>
                            <option value="Apartamento duplo com Ar">Apartamento duplo com Ar</option>
                            <option value="Apartamento de casal">Apartamento de casal</option>
                            <option value="Apartamento de casal com Ar">Apartamento de casal com Ar</option>
                            <option value="Apartamento de casal família com Ar">Apartamento de casal família com Ar</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="fone" id="telefone" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefone" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class='input-group date'  id='datetimepicker1'>
                                            <input type='text' class="form-control" name="data1" placeholder="Data de Entrada" />
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
                                            <input type='text' class="form-control" name="data2" placeholder="Data de Saída" />
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea id="obs" name="obs" class="form-control" rows="6" placeholder="Observação"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="tm-submit-btn" type="submit" name="submit">Reservar</button> 
                    </div>               
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>          
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Você está requerindo o arquivo `PHPMailerAutoload.php`, mas está dando erro em `PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php`? Estranho.

Comment: está dando outro erro.. editei

Comment: Defina melhor "novo erro". O primeiro não ocorre mais? O que mudou no seu código?

Comment: se está no mesmo diretório basta PHPMailerAutoload.php   e não  PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php

Comment: O primeiro erro não ocorre mais porque eu alterei a linha `PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php` para `PHPMailerAutoload.php`... mas agora passou a dar esse último erro.

Comment: o phpmailer requer as classes  class.phpmailer.php    class.pop3.php    class.smtp.php que deverão estar no mesmo diretório

Comment: eu coloquei essas três classes e coloquei os require e aparece este erro: `Warning: require(class.phpmailer.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Comment: Então [edite](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/189075/edit) sua pergunta e esclareça melhor o seu problema. Coloque a estrutura de arquivos e diretórios que está utilizando, bem como o código.

Comment: eu criei uma pasta chamada phpmailer e coloquei os três arquivos lá

Comment: o seu arquivo vc salvou na mesma pasta phpmailer? ou num diretório anterior?

Comment: nesse caso os quatro arquivos deverão estar na pasta phpmailer e na pagina enviar.php tem que estar  require "phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php";

Comment: e ai? deu certo? sono chegando por aqui

Comment: pra que dois require no arquivo php?  require("PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");   e   require_once('PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

Comment: basta um require

Comment: deu certooooooo... tirei o require a mais

Comment: vou soltar fogos hahaha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que o `PHPMailer` funcione corretamente são necessários quatro arquivos:

```
- PHPMailerAutoload.php
- class.phpmailer.php
- class.pop3.php
- class.smtp.php
```

Baixe esses quatro arquivos diretamente do [repositório](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) da biblioteca.

É importante que os quatro arquivos estejam no mesmo diretório. Por conveniência, coloque-os dentro de um diretório exclusivo, denomidado `PHPMailer`. Portanto, sua aplicação deve ficar parecida com:

```
enviar.php
PHPMailer/
    PHPMailerAutoload.php
    class.phpmailer.php
    class.pop3.php
    class.smtp.php
```

No arquivo `enviar.php`, coloque apenas:

```
require("PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
```

Os outros arquivos serão incluídos automaticamente quando necessários pela biblioteca.

Feito isso, poderá utilizar a biblioteca normalmente:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
...
```

Comment: no meu caso bastaram os 3 ultimos, pode entrar na minha pagina e mandar um mail que vai chegar aqui pra mim

Comment: Sim, mas não é uma boa prática (para iniciantes) a partir do momento que a própria documentação da biblioteca recomenda o uso do `autoload`.

Comment: eu fiz do jeito que pediu.. coloquei todos os arquivos no direitorio PHPMailer;.... erro: `require(PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in `

Comment: é vdd, houve mudança e não atualizei pq ainda assim funciona e mexer em algo agora pode dar ruim, pq uso isso em varias sites

Comment: Como está executando o arquivo `enviar.php`?

Comment: O formulário html está no mesmo arquivo enviar.php

Comment: o enviar.php está em que diretório?

Comment: no diretório raiz do site...

Comment: Então edite sua pergunta e coloque TODO o código, por favor. Coloque a estrutura de pastas também. Ninguém tem bola de cristal para descobrir o que você está fazendo.

Comment: pode ser só a parte de php?

Comment: E o formulário HTML.